# Доступ по IP адресу

Tags: c#, ip

Я администратор домена. Как мне с помощью C# получить доступ к папке Appdata на другом компьютере под активным сейчас пользователем? Работает пользователь за компьютером и просит меня помочь, как программно добраться до его папки аппдата? 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну как и всегда в windows:

```
\\CompDomainName\localdisk$\Documents And Settings\Myuser\Appdata
```

Вопрос в том, что ваше приложение должно в этой папке делать?

Вот пример копирования файла

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\admin\Downloads\npp.6.6.3.Installer.exe");
file.MoveTo(@"D:\end");
```

Соотвественно в первой строке вы указываете файл для копирования, а во второй строке вы ставите ваш сетевой адрес, куда надо скопировать файл.