# C# доступ к файлам на другой машине win - .nix

Tags: linux, windows, сеть

Нашел похожий вопрос: 
[Доступ по IP адресу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/394928/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BF%D0%BE-ip-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83)

Однако у меня ситуация в которой доступ надо получить с win7 к файлам на машине с linux (CentOS), вопрос даже не в том как это сделать, а хочется за ранее узнать сложнее ли это чем доступ к машине с тем же win7? Может быть и браться за это не стоит и установить на удаленный комп windows?

Comment: Можно например поднять на стороне `Linux` самбу. Или `FTP`. Тут все зависит от Ваших целей

Comment: Цель - вытаскивать записи разговоров Asterisk'a, запись в диалплане реализована и идет просто в указаную директорию .wav файлами. Не хотелось бы ставит винду и подымать freeswitch

Comment: Только вот выдергивание файлов должно осуществляться именно на ту машину где стоит клиент на C# написанный. Логика программы определяет какие именно файлы надо скопировать. То есть процесс должен идти по нажатию кнопки в клиенте или при его загрузке, не важно, важно, что по его инициативе. И не только по локалке.